# CSS justify text alignment on mobile

Tags: css, text, safari, alignment

For some reason headers in text are displaying as if they have text-align: justify property: 
[image: example]
I have tried to add text-align: left, but i did not help:

```
.post-content h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-text-align: left;
}
```

Same text block on PC: 
[image: another example]

Comment: Could please add more of your code? I think there are other rules affecting your issue.

Comment: I have just checked styles with dev tools and text-align: left is enabled. It is just mobile bug, because in PC all ok.
Also i have tried to change align to right and it works fine on PC, so this element is not affected by other rules.

Comment: Of which browser are we talking about? Still, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: On PC: Firefox, Chrome.
On mobile: Chrome, Safari.
Sorry, this is WordPress theme, so there is a large amount of code. Should I add it all?

Comment: please take a look at link above. Use the SO way for examples or make a codepen, with all the code that is necessary for this example to reproduce the issue. Otherwise we can only guess what's wrong. And guessing is not helping :(

Comment: I have created codepen with all HTML and CSS: https://codepen.io/domanskyi/pen/mgVjBe

Comment: In the pen it works as expected, please add more information about the browsers. OS & version will be helpful for reproduction

Comment: Hm, I just noticed the same thing - in CodePen all nice.
I checked it in Android 8.1 (Chrome version - 73.0.3683.90).
And in Iphone 7 in Chrome and Safari (it is my friend`s phone, so I dont know versions). Maybe it is just Chromium engine bug?

Comment: Yep, it is just in browsers with Chromium. I just checked it on mobile Firefox and there all is ok.

Comment: I can't replicate it. You could try to [remote debug with Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).